how can I merge multiple columns into array with datasets.Dataset.from_csv()?
I have a CSV file, it has N columns, if I do datasets.Dataset.from_csv(path), it will be N feature each of them is a int value.
However, I want to say: column-0 to column-4 is feature1, the rest is feature2. Is there a way to do this during reading?
if datasets cannot do it, can pyarrow do it?
If it is not possible during reading, is there an efficient way to transform the loaded dataset into the way I want?

What do you mean by merge columns? You want to turn 4 int columns into a nested pa.struct column with 4 ints?

nope, just array of 4 elements, no column name needed

One difficulty is that you have to pivot your column so they can be made into an arrow list array. The only way I can think of it to go through pandas / numpy to do this operation.
Take this table:
table = pa.table(
        {
            "col1": range(0, 4),
            "col2": range(4, 8),
            "col3": range(8, 12),
            "col4": range(12, 16),
            "col5": range(16, 20),
        }
    )




col1
col2
col3
col4
col5




0
4
8
12
16


1
5
9
13
17


2
6
10
14
18


3
7
11
15
19



Then you can do this:
array = pa.FixedSizeListArray.from_arrays(
    table.select(["col1", "col2", "col3"]).to_pandas().values.flatten(), 3
)
table = table.drop_columns(["col1", "col2", "col3"]).add_column(
    0, "array_feature", array.cast(pa.list_(pa.int64()))
)




array_feature
col4
col5




[0, 4, 8]
12
16


[1, 5, 9]
13
17


[2, 6, 10]
14
18


[3, 7, 11]
15
19



